# Springboot Kafka autoconfiguration - SSL Bundle for SASL_PLAINTEXT with SCRAM-SHA-512

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

Since SpringBoot version 3.2

> public Map<String, Object> buildAdminProperties()

is deprecated and marked for removal in version 3.4
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaProperties.html#buildAdminProperties()

and it is recommended to use

> public Map<String, Object> buildAdminProperties(SslBundles sslBundles)

As we are connecting to Kafka cluster using SASL_PLAINTEXT with SCRAM-SHA-512

```
  kafka:
    security:
      protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
    bootstrap-servers: adress_of_the_server
    properties:
      sasl:
        mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-512
        jaas:
          config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="username" password="password";
    jaas:
      enabled: true
```

how should I configure SslBundle for SASL_PLAINTEXT with SCRAM-SHA-512?

Comment: You can use `buildAdminProperties(null)` since Kafka SSL has nothing to do with Spring Boot SSL. On the other hand, it is better to rely on the auto-configured `KafkaAdmin`. If that still doesn't help, consider to share with us a simple project to let us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ArtemBilan - could you please elaborate an answer from this comment so I can accept it? It might be useful for other too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Boot auto-configures for us a `KafkaAdmin`. So, it is better to try to rely on that bean in your application. If you still have some specific use-case to create that instance yourself, consider to utilize `KafkaProperties.buildAdminProperties(null)` to obtain all those configuration properties. The `SslBundles` is part of Spring Boot configuration and does look like it can provide that `sasl` configuration for us. So, we just skip it and rely on whatever you have configured with those `properties` section in your YAML.